# SSRS 2016 report is failing with 'EXCELOPENXML' render format error

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

Few reports are failing with 'ExcelOpenXML' render format error after rs migration from 2014 to 2016.
I made following change to the RS config file so I can use old excel format however some of the reports are using 'ExcelopenXML' format. 
How can I use both 'Excel' and 'ExcelOpenXML' format so report will be sent out based on render format setup in subscription?

```
<!--Extension Name="EXCEL" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelRenderer.ExcelRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ExcelRendering" Visible="false"/-->
<Extension Name="EXCEL" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ExcelRendering"/>
<Extension Name="EXCELOPENXML" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ExcelRendering" Visible="false"/>
<!--Extension Name="WORD" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.WordRenderer.WordDocumentRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.WordRendering" Visible="false"/-->
<Extension Name="WORD" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.WordRenderer.WordOpenXmlRenderer.WordOpenXmlDocumentRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.WordRendering"/>
<Extension Name="WORDOPENXML" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.WordRenderer.WordOpenXmlRenderer.WordOpenXmlDocumentRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.WordRendering" Visible="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a couple of issues going on here.

1. You have the `*OPENXML` extension paths listed for both the legacy and new versions of both Excel and Word.  It looks like the proper extension paths for the legacy renderers are commented out in your config file.
2. The other issue is that you've got the `*OPENXML` extensions listed with the visibility flag set to `false`.

I think if you change the lines listed in your question to the following, all renderer options should show up in the dropdown on the subscription page:

```
<Extension Name="EXCEL" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelRenderer.ExcelRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ExcelRendering">
<Extension Name="EXCELOPENXML" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ExcelRendering"/>
<Extension Name="WORD" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.WordRenderer.WordDocumentRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.WordRendering">
<Extension Name="WORDOPENXML" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.WordRenderer.WordOpenXmlRenderer.WordOpenXmlDocumentRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.WordRendering"/>
```

More information on the Excel renderers can also be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-builder/exporting-to-microsoft-excel-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017#excel-2003-xls-renderer).

Comment: Thanks. I'll test in lower environment and see if it resolves the issue.